# Can I get a Malaysian visa if I have a departure ticket from Kuala Lumpur instead of a round-trip ticket?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, tickets, thailand, malaysia

I want to apply for Thailand and Malaysian visas, as I am visiting these 2 countries as a tourist.

**Can I get a visa for these 2 countries, without having a round-trip ticket?**

I'll book a ticket to Thailand, travel to Malaysia by road, and from Malaysia I have a return ticket back to India, will I be able to get a visa with this return ticket?